# Simplifying $\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\tan \alpha}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

How can one simplify
$$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\tan \alpha}\right)?$$
$0<α<\dfrac{\pi}{2}.$ Here is what I tried so far, 
$$\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{\tan \alpha}\right)=θ$$ for some θ.
$$\frac{1}{\tan \alpha}=\tan(θ)$$

I didn't know what to do next because there is no significant relationship between ${θ}$ and ${α}.$
I am stuck right here if there is some relation between θ and $\alpha$ that would make it a lot simpler.

Comment: When I checked using my calculator by inserting values for $α$ i found that it is equal to 90-$α$ for $α$ between 0 and 90 degrees but I could not know where to begin.

Comment: Draw a right triangle with acute angle $\alpha$ and an appropriate leg labeled by $\tan \alpha$; can you determine the remaining two sides?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recognize the complementary angle relation:

$$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\tanα}\right) =\arctan( \tan (\pi/2-\alpha) )  $$

$ \rightarrow (\pi/2 - \alpha), (3\pi/2 - \alpha),  $  plus co-terminal angles.

Answer (score 0):

When $\alpha=n\pi$ then $\arctan{1\over\tan\alpha}$ is undefined. Therefore we may assume that
$$-{\pi\over2}<\beta:=\bigl(n+{1\over2}\bigr)\pi-\alpha<{\pi\over2}$$
for a certain $n\in{\mathbb Z}$. I claim that
$$\arctan{1\over\tan\alpha}=\beta\ ,$$
whereby $\alpha=\bigl(n+{1\over2}\bigr)\pi$, i.e., $\tan\alpha=\pm\infty$, corresponds to $\beta=0$ in a natural way.

*Proof.* One has $-{\pi\over2}<\beta<{\pi\over2}$ by definition. When $0<\beta<{\pi\over2}$ then ${\pi\over2}-\beta=\alpha- n\pi$, so that we obtain
$$\tan\beta={1\over\tan\bigl({\pi\over2}-\beta\bigr)}={1\over\tan\alpha}\ ,$$
as required. Similarly one argues for $-{\pi\over2}<\beta<0$.

Comment: @travis yes, I understand $$\frac{1}{tan(α)} = tan(θ)$$ in which θ is the complementary angle of the right angle which is 90-$\alpha$ taking the inverse of gives $$θ=\tan^{-}\left(\frac{1}{tan(α)}\right)$$ , giving $$90-α=\tan^{-}\left(\frac{1}{tan(α)}\right)$$ thank you!

Comment: @community I actually arrived at this question while I was working a dynamics problem while derivating an equation to get the maximum value of a range of a projectile on an incline, I ended up in this equation. if I solved this equation(which I now did thanks to you) I found the maximum angle θ the velocity being thrown if the angle of the ramp( incline) is α the answer is $$\frac{90-α}{2}$$ the point is the problem came from a dynamics stand point but the problem was the mathematical minupilation so I thought it would fit for this site and therefore uploaded the question.